# Como colocar uma matriz bidimensional, sem tamanho definido em um struct em C, e acessar os elementos dessa matriz pelo próprio struct?

Tags: c

Sou iniciante em C, e estou tendo um pouco de problema com matrizes, structs e ponteiros.
Minha questão é um pouco confusa de entender, mas vamos lá. Eu tenho dois `typedef`, pra definir dois tipos de dados para um projeto que estou fazendo. Eis eles abaixo:

```c
typedef struct pixel {
    int red, green, blue;
} PIXEL;

typedef struct image {
    int width, height;
    PIXEL pixels[IMAGE.width][IMAGE.height];
} IMAGE;
```

Entretanto, eu estou confuso ao definir o último elemento do tipo, que deveria ser uma **matriz de elementos** do tipo `PIXEL`. Como eu não sei quantos elementos minha matriz terá, pensei que daria certo colocar os próprios atributos de altura e largura dentro da definição da minha matriz, mas não obtive sucesso.

O meu objetivo é conseguir ter essa matriz dentro do tipo `IMAGE` e ser capaz de acessar da seguinte forma:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < image.width; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < image.height; j++){
        printf("|%d, %d, %d", image.pixels[i][j].red, image.pixels[i][j].green, image.pixels[i][j].blue);
    }
    printf("|");
}
```

Isso deveria resultar em acessar os elementos da matriz criada dentro de `image`, e como cada elemento é do tipo PIXEL, e possui os atributos `red, green, blue`, também ser capaz de acessá-los.

Vi também que é possível utilizar um ponteiro para a matriz dentro do struct, de forma que o tipo ficaria assim:

```c
typedef struct image {
    int width, height;
    PIXEL *pixels;
} IMAGE;
```

Porém, não sei como trabalhar com essa estrutura. Venho do Python, e nele não temos ponteiros e structs, por isso fico um pouco confuso com tudo isso.

Ficaria extremamente grato se puderem me ajudar a pensar numa solução para esse problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque vetores são estáticos, o compilador deve saber o seu tamanho em tempo de compilação. Se o tamanho só vai ser definido em tempo de execução, o vetor deve ser alocado dinamicamente.

Exemplo de  uma função que aloca uma matriz (que também é um vetor, mas bidimensional) dinamicamente:

```
typedef struct image {
    int width, height;
    PIXEL** pixels;      // repare nos dois '*', para indicar que que é uma matriz
} IMAGE;


IMAGE make_image(int width, int height)
{
    IMAGE img;

    img.pixels = malloc(sizeof(PIXEL*) * height);

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        img.pixels[i] = malloc(sizeof(PIXEL) * width);
    }
    img.width  = width;
    img.height = height;
    return img;
}
```

A função acima cria uma imagem de tamanho `width`x`height`.